# Organic Groups Views

Tags: views, organic-groups

I would like to create a View which shows the Organic Group hierarchy in a side bar, see below for hierarchy. Also upon selecting content title from this sidebar, then shows the node content in the main page section, with or without a page reload.

1. I create a view with the 4 content types, but I cannot work out how to sort them by their hierarchy?
2. Also how do I then setup the view to show the Slide content in the main page section upon selection?

Content and Group Types:

Class: Group
Course: Group
Lesson: Group
Slide: Group Content

Organic Group hierarchy:

Class
 - Course
 - Course
 - Course
 - Course
 - - Lesson
 - - Lesson
 - - - Slide
 - - - Slide
 - - - Slide
 - Course
 - Course

Comment: In the past, I've used https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree to do this.

Comment: How have you setup the 'Main Field' and 'Parent Field' for the Views_Tree settings?